# How to use numpy.hist when i want the occurence of the indices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, histogram

I have a set of images and i want to create a histogram over the hue values from each image. Therfore i created an array with length 180. In every cell i add 1 if the hue value is in the image. 
In the end i have the array with the occurence of each hue value, but when i use numpy.hist, the y-axis are the hue values and the x-axis are the occurence. But i want it the other way round.

Here is my code:

```
path = 'path'
sub_path = 'subpath'

sumHueOcc = np.zeros((180, 1), dtype=int) 

print("sumHue Shape")
print(sumHueOcc.shape)

for item in dirs:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path,item)
    pathos = os.path.join(sub_path,item)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        img = np.array(Image.open(fullpath))

        f, e = os.path.splitext(pathos)

        imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

        print("Img shape")
        print(img.shape)

        # want to work with hue only
        h, s, v = cv2.split(imgHSV)

        # the hue values in one large array
        Z = h.reshape((-1, 1))
        # convert to np.float32
        Z = np.uint32(Z)

        # add 1 for each hue value in the image
        for z in Z:
            sumHueOcc[z] = sumHueOcc[z] + 1

        plt.figure(figsize=(9, 8))
        plt.subplot(311)  # Hue Picture 1
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
        plt.title("Hue Picture 1")
        plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(h), bins=180)
        plt.subplot(312)  # Hue Picture 2
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
        plt.title("Hue Picture 2")
        plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(Z), bins=180)
        plt.subplot(313)  # Hue Picture 2
        plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
        plt.title("Sum Occ")
        plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(sumHueOcc), bins=180)
        plt.show()

#First Hue Sum
plt.figure(figsize=(9,8))
plt.title("Sum Hue Occ")
plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(sumHueOcc), bins=180)
plt.show()
```

Here is Berriels Code with the change from Half Hue to Full Hue:

```
print(glob.glob('path with my 4 images'))

# list of paths to the images
image_fname_list = glob.glob('path with my 4 images')

# var to accumulate the histograms
total_hue_hist = np.zeros((359,))

for image_fname in image_fname_list:
    # load image
    img = cv2.imread(image_fname)
    # convert from BGR to HSV
    img = np.float32(img)
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL)
    # get the Hue channel
    #hue = img_hsv[:, :, 0]
    hue, sat, val = cv2.split(img_hsv)
    # show histogram
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(hue, bins=range(360))
    total_hue_hist += hist

plt.bar(list(range(359)), hist)
plt.show()
```

[Sum Occ has to be the same as Hue Picture 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlqjb.png)

[First of 4 Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVsJA.png)

[Second of 4 Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okaen.png)

[Third of 4 Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WNF6.png)

[Last of 4 Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32zk1.png)

[My result, which has to be correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVTYN.png)

[Berriels result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs3Kj.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load image
img = cv2.imread('lenna.png')
# convert from BGR to HSV
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# get the Hue channel
hue = img_hsv[:, :, 0]
# show histogram
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(hue, bins=range(180))
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist)
plt.show()
```

If you don't need to histogram values, you can do this way:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load image
img = cv2.imread('lenna.png')
# convert from BGR to HSV
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# get the Hue channel
hue = img_hsv[:, :, 0]
# show histogram
plt.hist(hue.flatten(), bins=range(180))
plt.show()
```

Input (`lenna.png`):

[image]

Output:

[image]

---

If you have multiple images, you can do something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# list of paths to the images
image_fname_list = ['lenna.png', 'other_image.png', ...]

# var to accumulate the histograms
total_hue_hist = np.zeros((179,))

for image_fname in image_fname_list:
    # load image
    img = cv2.imread(image_fname)
    # convert from BGR to HSV
    img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    # get the Hue channel
    hue = img_hsv[:, :, 0]
    # show histogram
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(hue, bins=range(180))
    total_hue_hist += hist

plt.bar(list(range(179)), hist)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution but it don't show the same result as it should be. The values are not in the range they had to be, see picture 3. My counting array has to be correct. I checked the array at index 38 and it showed me an value over 80.000, but in my histogram the value was under 10...

Comment: @MartinO why don't you just sum the `hist` values?

Comment: How? I print the shape of the hist array and its (10,). But i used the other alternative and stacked the images in an large array and then i can use numpy.hist to show the histogram for all the images. This worked for me.

Comment: @MartinO if you sum the `hist` variable of the code I provided, you could do this without stacking the images. The solutions are equivalent, but your solution has a `O(n)` memory footprint (where `n` is the number of images) and mine is `O(1)`. I updated the answer with a sample code at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I used your code but i get a different result. If i use my code, i get for the hue value 35 an occurence over 800.000. With your code, 35 hasn't the highest occurence, its occurence is over 120.000. The hue value 34 has the highest occurence with over 220.000, which is far away from 800.000, though...

Comment: My task is to seach in a video for hue values which the smallest occurence. Therfore i wanted to print an histogram over all images and to calculate the minimum. We solved the first part. For the calculation i created an array a with length 180 and then i go through all the hue values and add +1 for each occurence. In the end i have an array with length 180 and for example at a[35] i got the 800.000 value. Then i can search for the minimumin in the array. Do you have any better (faster) solution?

Comment: @MartinO yes I do, but this is a different question and comments are not appropriate for posting answers, according to SO guidelines. In SO, it is recommended that you open a new question instead. Once you open, post the link here so that I can help you solving this issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I don't know if it's really necessary to open a new question for that small question, because my solution is working... Weird, my mention of @ is not working... Anyway, i would select your answer, because your method is faster than mine, but as i said, the values in your histogram is not the values it has to be... Do you know why?

Comment: @MartinO update your question with your test image and I can investigate the reason (I missed the comment saying the results were different, sorry). About posting a new question: it is not about being a _small question_; it is more about stack overflow guidelines. We shouldn't post answers in the comments and OPs are not expected to expand their original question in order to accomodate _new_ needs; they should open new questions instead.

Comment: I updated my question. I used the Hue from 0-359, so i changed the code a bit, but this problem was also there with Hue from 0-179. I posted my changing of your code.

Comment: I understand that i have to open a new question for that. You are right. If this is the stack overflow guidelines, than i accept that :) Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419742/sum-of-the-occurence-of-colorhue-values0-359-from-a-set-of-images

Comment: @MartinO I see that your other question was already answered in a similar way I'd do. See? That's why it is better to open a new question :) I'll get back to this question tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I used the other alternative and put the images in one large vector and used the numpy.hist function for that vector. Then i get the right histogram for all images.

```
path = 'path'
sub_path = 'subpath'

sumHueOcc2 = np.zeros((1, 1), dtype=np.uint64) 
i=0

for item in dirs:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path,item)
    pathos = os.path.join(sub_path,item)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        img = np.array(Image.open(fullpath))

        f, e = os.path.splitext(pathos)

        #imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV) #numpy RGB

        # want to work with hue only
        h, s, v = cv2.split(imgHSV)

        # the hue values in one large array
        Z = h.reshape((-1, 1))
        # convert to np.float32
        Z = np.uint64(Z)

        # Huge vector of Images stack
        sumHueOcc2 = np.vstack((sumHueOcc2, Z))

        if i==0:
            sumHueOcc2 = np.delete(sumHueOcc2, (0), axis=0)
            i +=1


#Hue Sum for all images
plt.figure(figsize=(9,8))
plt.title("Sum Hue Occ")
plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(sumHueOcc2), bins=180)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This gives you one more zero than it should (the initial value of `sumHueOcc2`), therefore your histogram is wrong (one value, but it is). Also, `sumHueOcc2` grows linearly, which may not be a good idea. I updated my code in response to your comment.

Comment: @Berriel ok, for me this one value wasn't important because i got over 10k of occurances for each hue value, but i edited my code, so the first zero entry will be deleted. Now the vector is correct. But your point was absolutely correct, thank you!

Comment: If you consider using my code or find it helpful, also consider upvoting it, so that other users can easily see that a given answer contains something that may help them. Also, in SO, if you asked a question and now your problem is solved, it is recommended to either mark one of the answers as the answer or answering the question yourself and marking it as the answer. I'm leaving these comments because SO says "Martin O is a new contributor. Be nice, ..." :)

Comment: @Berriel Thank you. I upvoted your solution, but because i am new, it doesn't count... I want to mark your answer, because you tried to help me, but your result is not the result it has to be, because the values in your histogram aren't correct. Do you know why?