# Sum of the occurence of color(hue) values(0-359) from a set of images

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have a folder full of images and i want to find the Hue Values with the smallest occurence. For that i create an array with length 360 for all the hue values, take all the images in my folder, go through it and for each pixel i add +1 in my array at the index which represent the hue value. If i have for example the hue value 0 in my pixel, i add +1 in my array at index 0. 
My question is: is there a faster or more efficent way to do that?

Here is my code:

```
path = 'path'
sub_path = 'sub_path'
sumHueOcc = np.zeros((360, 1), dtype=np.uint64)

for item in dirs:
    fullpath = os.path.join(path,item)
    pathos = os.path.join(sub_path,item)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        f, e = os.path.splitext(pathos)
        img = np.array(Image.open(fullpath))
        img = np.float32(img)     
        imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL) #RGB because numpy RGB

        # want to work with hue only
        h, s, v = cv2.split(imgHSV)

        # the hue values in one large array
        Z = np.array(h, copy=True)
        Z = Z.reshape((-1, 1))

        # convert to np.float32
        Z = np.uint64(Z)

        # count each appearence from hue values
        for z in Z:
            sumHueOcc[z] = sumHueOcc[z] + 1


max = np.argmax(sumHueOcc)
min = np.argmin(sumHueOcc)
print("Minimum 1")
print(min)
sumHueOcc[min] += max
min = np.argmin(sumHueOcc)
print("Minimum 2")
print(min)
sumHueOcc[min] += max
min = np.argmin(sumHueOcc)
print("Minimum 3")
print(min)
sumHueOcc[min] += max
min = np.argmin(sumHueOcc)
print("Minimum 4")
print(min)
```

Comment: FYI, in OpenCV  H value is in (0, 180) for uint8 images

Comment: So basically you want a [histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) of your data?

Comment: @Miki Yes, i know. I accidantelly copied my code for the Half Hue. Now my code is correct.

Comment: @ThomasKühn yes and no. I have a histogram already. It was my other question. But i want the the value with the smallest occurence. Can i get that from a histogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `np.bincount` to do the counting.

So, we initialize the output array at the start with `int64` -

```
sumHueOcc_out = np.zeros((180, 1), dtype=np.int64)
```

Then, inside the loops, we replace the innermost section involving loops -

```
# the hue values in one large array
Z = np.array(h, copy=True)
Z = Z.reshape((-1, 1))

# convert to np.float32
Z = np.uint64(Z)

# count each appearence from hue values
for z in Z:
    sumHueOcc[z] = sumHueOcc[z] + 1
```

with `bincount` alternative -

```
sumHueOcc_out.flat += np.bincount(h.astype(np.int64).ravel(),minlength=sumHueOcc.size)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me why it is better/faster/more efficient? I don't see that now... Is it because in my loop i go trough all pixels and with np.bincount it goes through all pixels more efficent?

Comment: @MartinO Simply because we are using vectorized `bincount`.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with my other problem, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291952/how-to-use-numpy-hist-when-i-want-the-occurence-of-the-indices/ I want to have an efficent way to build a histogram. If i use sumHueOcc_out, it would swap the x and the y axis...

Comment: And sorry, my code was wrong at the beginning. I edited it. Now the range is from 0-359.

Comment: As a result, i have an array named sumHueOcc_out with length 360 and on each indices there is the value of the occurence. How can i print a histogram where on the x-axis the range is from 0-360 and on the y-axis there are the values from my array?